# QTCaptureDevice Closing By itself (FaceTime Camera) Mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a mac app that writes camera data to a file then uploads that file on an [NSTimer] to a server. However, after the camera runs for a while it closes itself and I see this in the log: *** QTCaptureDeviceInput warning: The device "FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)" was closed while still being used in a capture session. Make sure that the session is not running before closing any devices it is using.

No other apps are open that can use the camera in the test case and the object for the device is not being released by me. I have gone so far as to call retain on it to prevent this, to no avail.

I looked at Apple's docs and nowhere that I found did it talk about the camera being shut off by the system, so what could be causing this. In the meantime I have some code that periodically checks if it is open and if it isn't calls open on it.

One thing I forgot I am using this notification and it is being fired: QTCaptureDeviceWasDisconnectedNotification

Comment: does your problem go away if you take away that code that "periodically checks if it is open and if it isn't, calls open on it"? I suspect that's where your problem ultimately lies.

Comment: No I added after I saw the issue

Comment: Is there anything built into QT that would close the device due to memory or something like that?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann for good measure I took the code you referred to again, yet the problem persists.

Comment: I'm still thinking about this, too.  Can you set a breakpoint when `QTCaptureDeviceWasDisconnectedNotification` is fired and see if you can catch where/when the capture device is closed?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann So I just noticed in some testing that it seems to happen after 1 minute of recording; I am doing some network requests on a 10 sec timer and it always fails after the 6th run through.... I appreciate your help this is driving me mad

Comment: I just ran the app through analyzer and it looks fine from a memory perspective; it using around 120 mb steadily on a 8GB machine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it took a while but I found the issue. When you you are pulling image data from a running QTCaptureDevice you need to work with individual frames via the following delegate method. If you fail to properly release the buffers on each run the camera will eventually close by itself. Please note the code below is CORRECt; I attached it to help anyone else reading this question. Hope this saves someone the time it costed me...

```
- (void) captureOutput:(QTCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputVideoFrame:(CVImageBufferRef)videoFrame withSampleBuffer:(QTSampleBuffer *)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(QTCaptureConnection *)connection {
    CVBufferRef bufferToBeReleased;
    CVBufferRetain(videoFrame);
    @synchronized (self) {
        imageBufferToRelease = imageIWanted;
        imageIWanted = videoFrame;
    }
    CVBufferRelease(bufferToBeReleased);
}
```